# How to add two maps of hours and minutes and add them in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, timedelta

So I have two dicts of time durations:

```
a = {hours: 13, minutes: 23}
b = {hours: 23, minutes: 42}
```

and I want to add them together so the final output would be:

```
{hours: 37, minutes: 5}
```

Is there any python built in library that can help me do this or do I have to write my own function?

Comment: Do they each have just these two keys?

Comment: It's approximately 3 lines of code.  It would be quicker to write it than to search for a library.  The `datetime` module can do delta addition, but you'd have to convert to their format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the `dict` values to `datetime.timedelta` values is trivial, after which you can easily add them.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta(**a) + timedelta(**b)
datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=47100)
```

Converting the sum back to a `dict` is not so trivial, but still easy.

```
>>> x = timedelta(**a) + timedelta(**b)
>>> dict(zip(("hours", "minutes"), divmod(int(x.total_seconds())//60, 60)))
{'hours': 37, 'minutes': 5}
```

1. Converting the total number of seconds into minutes
2. Convert the minutes into hours and minutes
3. Zip with the strings `"hours"` and `"minutes"` to create
   a sequence of tuples suitable for passing to `dict`.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary keys must be hashable so let's make them strings. Then, break it down into simple steps:

```
a = {'hours': 13, 'minutes': 23}
b = {'hours': 23, 'minutes': 42}

def add_times(a, b):
    m = a['minutes'] + b['minutes']
    h = (0 if m < 60 else 1) + a['hours'] + b['hours']
    return {'hours': h, 'minutes': m % 60}

print(add_times(a, b))
```

**Output:**

```
{'hours': 37, 'minutes': 5}
```

Comment: @Mandera oops. Thank you. Edited

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that first sums together all time dicts and then moves over any extra hours from the minutes value.

```py
def sum_times(*time_dicts):
    summed = {key: sum(d[key] for d in time_dicts) for key in time_dicts[0]}
    summed["hours"] += summed["minutes"] // 60
    summed["minutes"] %= 60
    return summed
```

With your example

```py
a = {"hours": 13, "minutes": 23}
b = {"hours": 23, "minutes": 42}

print(sum_times(a, b))
```

```py
{'hours': 37, 'minutes': 5}
```